# MAC-Address based routing

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall

Here is what i want to do:

I have a bunch of systems, some might have the same Public-IP, i disable ARP. I have a Firewall (either IP Layer or bridge-FW) between these systems and the internet. Depending on the destination port of incoming IP-Packets to some of these Public-IPs i want to set the destinsation-Ethernet-Adress. So for instance

System A has IP 8.8.8.8, mac de:ad:be:ef:de:ad, arp disabled
System B has IP 8.8.8.8, mac 1f:1f:1f:1f:1f:1f, arp disabled

Firewall has IP 8.8.8.1, arp disabled on that interface

1. Incoming packet to IP 8.8.8.8 tcp dest port 100
2. Incoming  packet to IP 8.8.8.8 tcp dest port 101

Firewall sets dest-mac for 1.) -> de:ad:be:ef:de:ad
Firewall sets dest-mac for 2.) -> 1f:1f:1f:1f:1f:1f

Second scenario:

System A and System B establish outgoing TCP-Connections, and the firewall matches the dst-mac of the incoming IP-Packets (response packets) to the senders-mac address.

is this possible in any way with linux and iptables?

edit: i read ebtables might "work" in a hackish way for this purpose but i am not sure...

Comment: Looks to me like you're trying to solve what's already been solved several times over with a more elegant solutions.

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do is called port-forwarding, and is typically done via NAT.  (Incoming traffic on the public IP gets forwarded to a different private IP based on the port at which it arrives.)

Doing this via MAC address seems like an unnecessary complication.

Comment: i am well aware of port forwarding and NAT, but they are no options for me, because the end services have three requirements: 1.) they need to have a public IP and 2.) due to load balancing they may have different mac addreses 3.) due to limited public IPs several machines might have the same ip

Comment: Alright, well, good luck with that, then.  IPv6, FTW.

Comment: yeah ipv6 would obviously be the clean solution, unfortunately that doesnt help me atm because the services cant even use ipv6 yet

Comment: @d-fens Yeah, honestly sounds like you're just outta luck... I'd probably suggest to the suits that it would be a lot cheaper to buy more public IPs than to try to code through this... mess.

Comment: @d-fens - mac addresses are not routed.  It's irrelevant that the MAC is different.

Comment: i meant it as in layer-2 routing, as in "based on a set of criteria, decide what the destination ethernet-adress of a forwarded ip-packet should be, instead of just checking the arp table".

Answer (score 1):

Why get so complicated? Install a proxy or load balancer like haproxy and do everything at the layer 3 level.

Comment: i have services i load balance. these services must bind() to a public IP and even establish outgoing connections through this public IP. Due to load balancing the services might end up on different nodes. Due to oforementioned necessity of public IPs, different nodes might have the same ip, for example a service A and B has both bind() to 8.8.8.8 but service B was later migrated to another node.

Answer (score 0):

One method which may work well for you is by using a the nth module in iptables.
I haven't tested this but in theory you should be able to make this work.

For example:

Will load balance requests to port 100 to 2 internal servers.

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 100 -m state --state NEW -m nth --counter 0 --every 2 --packet 0 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.1:100

iptables -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 100 -m state --state NEW -m nth --counter 0 --every 2 --packet 1 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.2:100
```

By the way, firewall can still have 8.8.8.1 address if you like and also 8.8.8.8.  You can write NAT rules so that traffic coming from those servers exiting the firewall will use 8.8.8.8 as their source. Any other traffic behind the firewall can use 8.8.8.1 as the source.

Something like the following may work.

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/30 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source 8.8.8.8
```

Where only ip's from 192.168.1.0 - 192.168.1.3 are allowed. i.e. your servers

And for the rest of the network

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source 8.8.8.1
```

Yeah I know, the 30 range is inside the 24 range.  iptables will hit the first rule and NAT to 8.8.8.8 (I think).

Comment: Nat is not going to work unfortunately, because the services use the bind() socket parameters to propagate the service to third party directories. For instance if i use 192.168.x.x that IP would be propagated to the lookup directory, regardless what kind of NAT-foo i make.

Comment: ok, can you change that logic?  what happens when you need to change public IP? isn't this all going to come crashing down in a big heap?

Comment: What about putting each machine in a different VLAN bound to the same IP?  then you can route by VLAN